# Ubuntu 5.11.0-25 WI-FI and Bluetooth no WI-FI adapter found and no Bluetooth found

Tags: iwlwifi

After a reboot following an update, the WI-FI and Bluetooth stopped working. The setting shows that it cannot find the adapter eventhough same desktop works fine on Windows via a dual-boot. I have MSI MEG X570 ACE with Intel AX200 built-in.

When I restart and pick Advanced options from the menu, If I pick 5.11.0-25 or 5.11.0-22 (generic or recovery) - still WI-FI and bluetooth do not show up. If I pick 5.8.0-43, works like it used to.

Is this a bug? Is there a fix or workaround?

I do have firmware @ /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode

```
modinfo iwlwifi
modinfo: ERROR: Module iwlwifi not found.
```

---

```
sudo cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=false
WWANEnabled=true
```

---

```
lspci -vnn | grep 'Network'
26:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1462:7c35]
28:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
```

---

```
rfkill list
```

returns nothing

---

```
sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status
Status: install ok config-files
```

---

Thank you,

H. Salka

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Status: install ok config-files

In a normal default install, this reads:

```
Status: install ok installed
```

Please reinstall the package:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

Reboot and show us:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour